# Material 3 NavigationBarItem: How to change selected and unselected icons?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Can the image of a `NavigationBarItem` icon be changed whenever the `NavigationBarItem` is selected or unselected?

**Current result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

```
sealed class BottomNavItem(var title: String, var icon: ImageVector, var screen_route: String){
    object Users: BottomNavItem("Users", Icons.Filled.AccountBox,"users")
    object Notifications: BottomNavItem("Notifications", Icons.Filled.Notifications,"notifications")
}

items.forEach { item ->
    NavigationBarItem(
        icon = { Image(imageVector = item.icon, contentDescription = item.title) },
        label = { Text(text = item.title) },
        alwaysShowLabel = true,
        selected = currentRoute == item.screen_route,
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(item.screen_route) {
                navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { screen_route ->
                    popUpTo(screen_route) {saveState = true}
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
                restoreState = true
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace parameter `icon:ImageVector` of class `BottomNavView` to two parameters: `iconFilled:ImageVector` and `iconOutlined:ImageVector`.

```
sealed class BottomNavItem(var title: String, var filledIcon: ImageVector,var outlinedIcon:ImageVector, var screen_route: String){
    object Users: BottomNavItem("Users", Icons.Filled.AccountBox,"users")
    object Notifications: BottomNavItem("Notifications", Icons.Filled.Notifications,"notifications")
}
```

You will use `iconFilled` for selected menu item and `iconOutlined` for all unselected items. So replace foreach loop with this code:

```
items.forEach { item ->
    val selected = currentRoute == item.screen_route
    NavigationBarItem(
        icon = { Image(imageVector = if(selected) item.filledIcon else item.outLinedIcon, contentDescription = item.title) },
        label = { Text(text = item.title) },
        alwaysShowLabel = true,
        selected = selected,
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(item.screen_route) {
                navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { screen_route ->
                    popUpTo(screen_route) {saveState = true}
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
                restoreState = true
            }
        }
    )
}
```